# Anyone know how to track disconnection of Heart Rate service in bluez?

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on BLE using python library bluez. I created a GATT Server with Heart Rate Service (180d)and added 2a37 characteristics with notify method using Dbus API. It works fine, it sends notification properly after connection establish. But, if by any means, if bluetooth connection breaks from client, i don't get any callback on server. A method is available StopNotify which is called when ever client disable Notification.
Anyone know any such method which inform server about Disconnection ?